# how to find the timestamp of a branch in tfs

Tags: tfs, visual-sourcesafe

How can we find when a branch is created in TFS? When we are using VSS, we used to create Label for every release and we can see the timestamp of the label to find when a release is done. Now I am not able to find when a label is created or a branch is created in TFS 2010. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Source Control explorer:

- Right click on the branch (or any folder, or any file that you are interested in) and `View History`
- You can view either change-sets or labels by changing the tab at the top of the history view

Comment: Hi Williams, thanks for the reply! But I am not able to see any tabs in the history View. I think the problem is with me. I forgot to say that i am connecting to TFS 2010 from Visual Studio 2005! So hope VS2005 dont have that feature.

Comment: I'm surprised you get even that much functionality working when using vs2005 with tfs 2010. I haven't used 2005 for 5 years so I'm afraid I can't helpyou with specifics of where labels can be found in the UI. I'd suggest using vs 2010 to view the source control information even if you have to return to 2005 to write your code.

Comment: Yes, I am also thinking the same, we have to use it separately! I will suggest this to my boss.. Thanks again.